# how to let Iphone load videojs using "vhs.xhr.beforeRequest"?

Tags: iphone, video.js

Facing an issue with Iphone only, that can't process what inside "beforeRequest", on any browser including chrome and firefox, otherwise on Ipad and android works as a rock.

I tried to use true and false for "overrideNative" also nothing.

tried to console inside "beforeRequest" on Iphone and there is no return.

I found this error on debugger:

`ERRORVIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:3 MEDIA_ERR_DECODE) The media playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the media used features your browser did not support. [object Object]`

```
player.tech({ IWillNotUseThisInPlugins: true }).vhs.xhr.beforeRequest =  (options)=> console.log('beforeRequest'))
```

anyone has a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't. VHS is used to play HLS with Media Source Extensions, which iPhone doesn't not support. Only native playback is possible.